# php xpath - get last attribute

Tags: php

If some nong has accidentally entered the same attribute more than once in the same tag how do I select the last one??? (By default it seems to select the first... I'm not sure if this is how attribute hierarchy works in html?)

Using the example below...

Query: "./@href"
Tag: 
Expected Result: "2.html"
Result: "1.html"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you get a

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Attribute href redefined in Entity
```

message on load()/loadxml()
[W3C says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#attdecls):

> When more than one definition is provided for the same attribute of a given element type, the first declaration is binding and later declarations are ignored.

Comment: excellent! - the easiest answers are sometimes the hardest to find. Thanks for the link too